# No "File Panels Help" panel

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

What I see:

[image: What I see]

What I want to see:

[image: What I want to see]

I'm new to ROS and Linux and I'm really confused by this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284232/no-%22file-panels-help%22-panel./) by [Chput](https://answers.ros.org/users/33949/chput/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2018-03-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-02**:
We're also confused. Please attach your images directly to your question, instead of linking to an offsite location.

**Comment by [Chput](https://answers.ros.org/users/33949/chput/) on 2018-03-02**:
Post edited.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-02**:
Is it perhaps at the top of the screen in the menu bar there? Does it change if you maximize the window? Maybe this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/541449/how-do-i-always-show-menu-items-in-unity#610237

**Comment by [Chput](https://answers.ros.org/users/33949/chput/) on 2018-03-03**:
Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using the Unity window management (default on recent versions of Ubuntu) you need to mouse over the title bar at the top to see the File menu at the top. If you move your mouse to the top of the screen I suspect you'll see it there.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chput](https://answers.ros.org/users/33949/chput/) on 2018-03-03**:
Thanks a lot! The issue seemed to be simple to answer, but so complicated to find answer ^^